# Eliminating values from one table with another. Super slow

Tags: mysql, sql

In the same datbase I have a table `messages` whos columns: `id`, `title`, `text` I want. I want only the records of which `title` has no entries in the table `lastlogon` who's title equivalent is then named `username`.

I have been using this SQL command in PHP, it generally took 2-3 seconds to pull up:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages WHERE title NOT IN (SELECT username FROM lastlogon) LIMIT 1000`

This was all good until the table `lastlogon` started to have about 80% of the values table `messages`. Messages has about 8000 entries, lastlogon about 7000. Now it takes about a minute to 2 minutes for it to go through. MySQL shoots up to very high CPU usage.

I tried the following but had no luck reducing the time:

`SELECT id,title,text FROM messages a LEFT OUTER JOIN lastlogon b ON (a.title = b.username) LIMIT 1000`

Why all of a sudden is it taking so long for such low amount of entries? I tried restarting mysql and apache multiple times. I am using debian linux.

Edit: Here are the structures

```
--
-- Table structure for table `lastlogon`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lastlogon` (
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `lastlogon` date NOT NULL,
  `datechecked` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `messages`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` smallint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text` mediumtext,
  `folder` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `read` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateline` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `attachment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9010 ;
```

Edit 2

Edited structure with new indexes.
After putting an index on both messages.title and lastlogon.username I came up with these results:

Showing rows 0 - 29 (623 total, Query took 74.4938 sec)

Comment: Do you have an index on `lastlogon.username`?

Comment: Can you include the explain plan?  I'm expecting it will answer Clive's question by saying that there is no index, and a full table scan is being performed.

Comment: uses `lastlogon.username` is the primary key. whereasin `messages` it has a separate primary key called `id`.

Comment: @BHare: As I understand it the index created would be across the two primary keys and not one for each column (although I could well be wrong), try adding an index specifically for the `username` column

Answer (score 1):

First: replace the key on title, with a compound key on title + id

```
ALTER TABLE messages DROP INDEX title;
ALTER TABLE messages ADD INDEX title (title, id);
```

Now change the select to:

```
SELECT m.* FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN lastlogon l ON (l.username = m.title)
WHERE l.username IS NULL
-- GROUP BY m.id DESC -- faster replacement for distinct. I don't think you need this.
LIMIT 1000;
```

Or

```
SELECT m.* FROM messages m
WHERE m.title NOT IN (SELECT l.username FROM lastlogon l)
-- GROUP BY m.id DESC -- faster than distinct, I don't think you need it though.
LIMIT 1000;
```

Another problem with the slowness is the `SELECT m.*` part.
By selecting all column, you are forcing MySQL to do extra work.
Only select the columns you need:

```
SELECT m.title, m.name, m.email, ......
```

This will speed up the query as well.

**There's another trick you can use:**
Replace the limit 1000 with a cutoff date.

Step 1: Add an index on timestamp (or whatever field you want to use for the cutoff).

```
SELECT m.* FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN lastlogon l ON (l.username = m.title)
WHERE (m.id > (SELECT MIN(M2.ID) FROM messages m2 WHERE m2.timestamp >= '2011-09-01'))
  AND l.username IS NULL
-- GROUP BY m.id DESC -- faster replacement for distinct. I don't think you need this.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add an index on `messages.title` . Then try to run again the query and test the performance.

Comment: Didn't really help.Any other ideas?

Comment: @BHare You mean that you get the same speed or that the improvement is not so good as you're searching for?

Comment: Including the explain plan to your query will help immensely.

Comment: @BHare Dems is right. Besides, I see your edit and I understand that the query has an improvement of 35-40% about which is not insignificant. Anyway I think that also if you can do other optimization, you'll never back to 2-3 seconds or something like this. The better way you can follow, in my opinion, is to use a caching system.